# What process is causing unexpected nslcd syslog entries?

Tags: linux, authentication, syslog

We're using LDAP for authenticating users our devices using nslcd and we're seeing messages in syslog like this:

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 06:25:11 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [398c89] <passwd="*"> "*": name denied by validnames option
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 06:25:11 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [4fe9f9] <passwd="*"> "*": name denied by validnames option
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 06:25:14 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [b5af5c] <passwd="*"> "*": name denied by validnames option
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 06:25:15 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [1226bb] <passwd=-1> ldap_search_ext() failed: Can't contact LDAP server
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 06:25:15 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [1226bb] <passwd=-1> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 06:25:16 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [34b6a8] <passwd="*"> "*": name denied by validnames option
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 06:25:16 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [233c99] <passwd=-1> ldap_search_ext() failed: Can't contact LDAP server
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 06:25:16 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [233c99] <passwd=-1> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 09:01:04 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [0c57b1] <passwd=-1> ldap_search_ext() failed: Can't contact LDAP server
/var/log/syslog.1:Dec 20 09:01:04 T53-1014-014 nslcd[1496]: [0c57b1] <passwd=-1> no available LDAP server found, sleeping 1 seconds
```

We want to get rid of these messages without simply reconfiguring what is logged. So preferably we learn what is going on and reconfigure the system such that these messages are no longer generated in the first place. But how to analyse this?

The problem is that any process can do something that triggers the system to perform an authentication action and in the log you cannot see which process is triggering the authentication action. Any thoughts on how to analyse this?

I'm fine with adding extra diagnostic code to the source of nslcd if that helps and deploying that instrumented executable.

We're using an old Ubuntu distro: 12.04, nss-pam-ldapd-0.8.4

---

Update: I've created a modified version of nslcd which logs the command line of the applications that connect to it. This helps a lot, obviously.

Comment: Do you care to share which OS/version/distribution/release you're using? That would be helpful.

Comment: It might be helpful to paste relevant entries/files from `/etc/pam.d` and `/etc/nslcd.conf` as well.

Comment: Hi, would you share some results of your investigations ? I am too seeing scores of seemingly idiotic ldap requests by nslcd in my system.

Answer (score 0):

From `man 5 nslcd.conf`

> validnames REGEX
>
> This option can be used to specify how user and group names are verified within the system. This pattern is used to check all user and
>   group names that are requested and returned from LDAP.
>
> The regular expression should be specified as a POSIX extended regular expression. The expression itself needs to be separated by
>   slash (/) characters and the 'i' flag may be appended at the end to
>   indicate that the match should be case-insensetive. The default value
>   is /^[a-z0-9.*@$()]([a-z0-9.*@$() \~-]*[a-z0-9._@$()~-])?$/i

I assume you are attempting to request a username with a '*' in it (probably an indication of someone thinking file globbing works on usernames) or responding messages coming out of ldap contain a user with a '*' in it.

You could either attempt to resolve the offending username or alter the `validnames` regex such that it accepts '*' as a valid user name.

**Note** that doing this may lead to unexpected problems, especially in shell scripts where '*' is used as an expression if its not properly escaped or quoted.